MySQL to SSRS report builder
I am struggling to connect MySQL database to SSRS.
I am struggling to connect MySQL database to SSRS. I have connected to report builder but when I publish on the ssrs server, it does not open the report becuase I need to add data source on ssrs which I dont know how to do.
